# EditText binding cause NULL / 0 text for int variable

Tags: android, android-databinding

I have a `Integer` value in `model`, and set it to `EditText` by data binding.

**Problem** is that when page loads first time, then `null` or default value (0) is set to `EditText`, whether I want `EditText` **hint** to be **shown**.

#### Try 1st : with Non-Primitive type `Integer`

```
private Integer storeCount;
android:text="@={model.storeCount+``}"
```

[image: try1]

#### Try 2nd : with Primitive type `int`

```
private int storeCount;
android:text="@={model.storeCount+``}"
```

[image: try2]

#### Try 3rd : null check

```
 android:text="@={model.storeCount == null ? null :(model.storeCount+``)}"
```

This cause compile time error.

Any solution please?

Answer (score 1):

You should change its datatype to String instead of using int or Integer i.e `private String storeCount;`

and add one new attribute to EditText as `android:inputType="number"` 
So that it will allow user to input number only. While fetching the value from EditText convert its value to int i.e `Integer.parseInt(value)`

Comment: Bro, I ended up with this solution yesterday, but wanted to know if it is not possible to do so.